# how to fix a width with a display:inline box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to layout a couple of div's inline and want to give them a fixed width. I currently have:

```
  <style>
    .af-header{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }



    .menu-item-header{
      border: 1px solid blue;
      width: 200px;

    }

    .menu-item-detail{
      border:1px solid orange;
      width: 400px;

    }

    .menu-item{
      border: 1px solid red;

    }

  </style>

  <table class='af-header'>
    <tr>
      <td width=800>
      <div class='menu-item'>
      <div class='menu-item-header'>my header</div>
      <div class='menu-item-detail'>here is my detail</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

The problem that I'm having is that the menu-item-header and menu-item-detail collapse down to fit the text like in the following screenshot:

[image]

How do I fix the width in these two so that the width is respected?

Comment: why you use table in the first place?

Comment: @Roko use what I know :-) it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` not `display: inline`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` for your `div` elements to put them in line

```
.af-header div
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hBy92/)

I'm not sure why are you using `table` here, if it only to take the advantage of column effect then you don't need to use it. You can use just div to achieve the same

```
<div class="af-header">
    <div class='menu-item'>
        <div class='menu-item-header'>my header</div>
        <div class='menu-item-detail'>here is my detail</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Js Fiddle without table](http://jsfiddle.net/hBy92/1/)

Comment: re table, there's a bit more to the layout and the predictable structuring is useful.

Comment: @timpone If the table is strictly for layout purposes, use semantic markup and style it with `display: table`, etc. The HTML table is only for tabular data and should never be used as a layout technique.

Comment: @timpone avoid using table wherever possible in designing.  You can also search for `div vs table` but one of them is here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Comment: what clear benefit do I achieve? not saying that be snarky but I always hear that and up till  a year or two ago, google's home page used a table for layout https://web.archive.org/web/20110604111129/http://www.google.com/

Comment: @timpone that was probably IE7 support